# Flex spark datagrid with big real time data

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, datagrid

i'm currently facing issues with a spark datagrid that is linked to an arrayCollection in witch data are added in "real time" I mean the content is always changing.

But the whole application freezes, is there a way to redraw only some parts of the datagrid ?

EDIT : 
I tried to run my application with no binding between my arrayCollection and the datagrid.
I receive the data using a socket connection, and the interface still freezes, how can i give a chance to the interface to refresh during the data reception ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Only the visible renderers are redrawn anyway, so the bottleneck is most likely to be found elsewhere, but we can't tell unless you provide more information and/or code.

Comment: @RIAstar In the MX DataGrid; lots of columns could slow things down because all columns were rendered [for visible rows] even if the columns were offscreen.  I'm not sure if the Spark DataGrid has the same limitation or not.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how many objects are coming in to the application and how heavy the objects are, the UI could be hanging up during object instantiation for all the incoming data.  If the goal is to display the data in a grid, you might want to look into pagination.  The Flex grids have the ability to automatically request the next page as you scroll.

Comment: OK, thanks for your response, I've continued to test the case, and in fact via a socket connection, I receive data permanently, and as i add them to the datagrid, it nevers refreshes, I'd like to find a way to force datagrid refresh

Comment: it might be helpful to post some code.  If you have your grid dataProvider bound to an ArrayCollection and the grid's not updating, that sounds unusual.